# Protecting routes in laravel with filters

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-routing

how can I secure routes so that user can access only those departments that he belongs to? 
my current filter:

```
    Route::filter('department', function ($route, $request) {
        // Check to see if the current user belongs to the department:
       if (!Request::isMethod('post'))
       {
        if($request->segment(2) != "create")
        {
            if (!Auth::user()->canAccessDepartment($request->segment(2))) {
                // The user shouldn't be allowed to access the department! Redirect them
                return Redirect::to('/')->with( 'notice', 'Error!' );;
            }
        }
    }
    });
```

And this is my method in user model

```
   public function canAccessDepartment($department_id) {
         $user = Confide::user();

        if ($user->departments()->where('department_id', $department_id)->count() < 1) 
        {
            return false;
        }
        else{ return true; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have, the filter is applied to all the routes, and then checks to see if we have a matching method/action.  My preference would be to only apply the filter when it's needed.  So

[Warning - untested code follows]

```
Route::resource('department', 'DepartmentController',
                array('except' => array('create','store', 'update', 'destroy')));

Route::resource('department','DepartmentController',array('only'=>array('create','store', 'update', 'destroy'),'before'=>'departmentFilter'));


Route::filter('department', function ($route, $request) {
   // should this be Confide::user() ?
   if (!Auth::user()->canAccessDepartment($request->segment(2))) {
       // The user shouldn't be allowed to access the department! Redirect them
       return Redirect::to('/')->with( 'notice', 'Error!' );
    }
});
```

Comment: It is working when I access specific department domain/department/2, but if I try to access domain/department (which would list all departments) I get "error" with redirect to '/'

Comment: When you access domain/department, it's going to call the index() function on your controller.  What does the code in there look like?

Comment: Only this 
  return View::make('department.index');

Comment: The one I have in filter you wrote, "Error!"

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should be done in the database/model level. Since the data that you need to compare is in a database, its better if you do this transaction in a database level.